# How to query (CQL) a Cassandra composite PK table with one-to-many PK column relationship?

Tags: cassandra, cql, composite-primary-key

I have a cassandra table:

```
PropertiesOfThing
------------------
thingID text
propertyName text,
propertyValue,
primary key (thingID, propertyName)
```

records can be:

```
thingID propertyName propertyValue
1       x            v1x
1       y            v1y
2       y            v2y
```

How do I find thingID(s) that do not have a specific propertyName for example x? What is the right CQL?

Comment: The "Cassandra" way to do this is to use one table for each select query you're likely to do - model it in such a way that the query is natural.

Comment: How should I model it to find out thingID that don't have propertyName=x (result should be thingID=2)- can you please explain?

Comment: You can't query like this, but you can get the List of thingID that have specific propertyName